# TestNG No tests found. Nothing was run while try to automate rest api

Tags: eclipse, rest-assured

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZP6j.png)

I don't know why I'm getting this error can anyone help me out with this??

I'm simply trying to create get request via rest assured. I'm getting this error due to some missing jar files or anything else I'm not sure I tried all the posted solutions from the Stack Overflow.   In my Java build path, i have testng the library and tries that as well but still errors.

Comment: It seems you missed `@Test` for the method and method should not be static (not quite sure)

Answer (score 0):

This error message

> [TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run

implies that TestNG didn't find any **@Test** to execute. As i can see in the screenshot you have not used **@Test annotation** in the *getUsers* test. Just import this annotation and use it above the *getUsers* test line.